# Is there a standard UWP "Symbols & Special Characters" dialog that I can use in my app?

Tags: xaml, unicode, uwp, windows-10-universal, symbols

I have a basic word-processing Universal Windows app running on Windows 10 desktop devices.

I'd like to support adding symbols and special characters such as greek letters and mathematical operators.

Is there a UWP system UI that I could present?

In Word/Powerpoint there is the menu "Insert → Symbol" that brings up this window:

[image: Symbols dialog]

Is it possible to present this dialog or something similar from a UWP app? I'd like to avoid having to re-implement this.

Closest thing I found is pressing the Windows Key + ; but that only brings up a window for inserting emoji, not symbols:

[image: emoji]

Comment: If you decide to implement it on your own, look at the feature set of the state of the art Unicode character picker applications: https://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/ http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html https://codepoints.net/

Answer (score -1):

You may use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol
Or special fonts or svg icons.

Comment: That's just an enum related to a Microsoft-specific font with special appbar icons. It doesn't include Greek letters or mathematical operators like OP was asking for.